# JSF ValueChangeListener not called for composite with backing component

Tags: jsf-2, composite-component, valuechangelistener

I'm trying to capture old/new value for some business validation. For that, the ValueChangeListener seemed like a good choice. It worked great on h:selectOneMenu, however it does not get called when used with a home grown Composite Component with a Backing Component. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

One thing to add is, when removing the componentType attribute from state.xhtml, the valueChangeListener works as expected...

The component:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

    <composite:interface displayName="state" componentType="com.company.dept.system.ui.address.State" shortDescription="State Information Display/Input Component">
        <composite:attribute name="value" type="java.lang.String" required="true" shortDescription="The value of the component" />      
        <composite:editableValueHolder name="state" />              
    </composite:interface>

    <composite:implementation>
    <div id="#{cc.clientId}">

            <h:selectOneMenu id="state" value="#{cc.attrs.value}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="(select)" noSelectionOption="true"/>
                <f:selectItems var="item" itemLabel="#{item.displayValue}" value="#{cc.states}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>      

    </div>

    </composite:implementation>
</html>
```

The backing component

```
@FacesComponent("com.company.dept.system.ui.address.State")
public class State extends UIInput implements NamingContainer {

    private List<com.company.dept.policy.enums.State> states;

    @Override
    public String getFamily() {
        return UINamingContainer.COMPONENT_FAMILY;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare the list of states to display
     */
    public List<com.company.dept.policy.enums.State> getStates(){

        if (states != null) {
            return states;
        }

        states = new ArrayList<com.company.dept.policy.enums.State>();              
        for (com.company.dept.policy.enums.State st : com.company.dept.policy.enums.State.values()) {
            if(!st.equals(com.company.dept.policy.enums.State.NWNORWAY) && !st.equals(com.company.dept.policy.enums.State.UNKNOWN) &&  !st.equals(com.company.dept.policy.enums.State.TTTRUST_TERRITORY_AND_GUAM)) {            
                states.add(st);
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(states,new StateNameComparator());

        return states;
    }

}
```

The value change listener

```
public class ClientValueChangeListener implements ValueChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void processValueChange(ValueChangeEvent event)
            throws AbortProcessingException {
        System.out.println("*****************************");
        System.out.println("VALUE CHANGE LISTENER. OLD=" + event.getOldValue() + " - NEW=" + event.getNewValue());
        System.out.println("*****************************");
         }
}
```

consuming page:

```
<h:form>
    <address:state value="#{testPage.state}">
        <f:valueChangeListener type="com.company.dept.system.ui.clientinformation.ClientValueChangeListener" for="state"/>
    </address:state>
    <h:commandButton id="submitButton" value="Test" action="#{testPage.act}"/>          
</h:form>
```

Comment: Which JSF impl/version? What if you explicitly specify `<cc:editableValueHolder targets>`?

Comment: Using Mojarra 2.1.13 on jBoss EAP 6. I tried setting targets="state" on editableValueHolder but it had no effect.

Comment: I now see that your backing component extends from `UIInput`. I'd say, just get rid of it. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your backing component extends from `UIInput`. The value change listener is applied to the backing component itself instead of to a child of the composite implementation.

Your concrete functional requirement isn't exactly clear, but based on the information provided so far, you can safely replace `extends UIInput implements NamingContainer` by `extends UINamingContainer` (and get rid of `getFamily()` override).

If you really intend to keep your backing component to extend from `UIInput`, then you should be delegating the submitted value, local value and value of the backing component all to the child dropdown component, but this makes design technically little to no sense.

Comment: That was the problem! Extended UINamingContainer instead and the listener started working! Thanks!
BTW, the business requirement is having a State dropdown with prepackaged look and feel.

Comment: You're welcome. If you ever intend to use **multiple** input components in your composite and intend to get/set it via a **single** value property, then you should indeed let your backing component extend from `UIInput`, but this requires obviously a little more work. But do note that in such case, it would make little sense anyway to target a specific child input component with a value change listener.

Comment: I have other components that extend UIInput and override encodeBegin, getSubmittedValue, and getConvertedValue. It was a lot of work to put those together, and I still don't fully understand what all of the methods do and what other methods are available. Can you recommend an advanced tutorial that explains Backing Components?

Comment: It helps maybe to see one sensible real world use case: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2013/01/composite-component-with-multiple-input.html If your composite doesn't contain multiple input components whose value should be get/set from a single bean property, then you most likely don't need this approach at all.